# VB.NET how to get DATA in JSON File using deserialize

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

This is my sample JSON response

```json
"responseCode": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "5177812010609887065",
            "form_id": "220108733897057",
            "ip": "136.158.10.60",
            "created_at": "2022-01-12 02:20:01",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "new": "1",
            "flag": "0",
            "notes": "",
            "updated_at": null,
            "answers": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "heading",
                    "order": "1",
                    "text": "Form",
                    "type": "control_head"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "submit2",
                    "order": "3",
                    "text": "Submit",
                    "type": "control_button"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "order": "2",
                    "sublabels": "{\"prefix\":\"Prefix\",\"first\":\"First Name\",\"middle\":\"Middle Name\",\"last\":\"Last Name\",\"suffix\":\"Suffix\"}",
                    "text": "Name",
                    "type": "control_fullname",
                    "answer": {
                        "first": "pogi",
                        "last": "awdwad"
                    },
                    "prettyFormat": "pogi awdwad"
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to get "first" and "last" value using vb.net newtonsoft JSON using vb.net.

Comment: `Dim first = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)("content")(0)("answers")("3")("answer")("first")` -- The JSON you posted here is missing pieces (`{` and `] }`).

Comment: You should probably build class objects that describe the JSON. [This on-line service](https://jsonutils.com/) produces .Net classes in the VB.Net language from a (valid) JSON.

Comment: I uploaded the "full json file" from your [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690278/3744182) to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, and when parsed it generated many errors.  In particular, the values of the `"sublabels"` string are malformed, with incorrectly escaped inner quotes.  Is your JSON really malformed in that manner?  If so, you are not going to be able to parse it with Json.NET.  In fact I don't think any of the main JSON parsers available for .NET offer fault-tolerant parsing of malformed JSON out of the box.

Comment: thank you already answered by @Jimi. thank you. this code work.